# (node:14688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of null

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, discord, discord.js

```
    //music commands
```

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

var servers = {};

let args = message.content.substring(`${prefix}`.length).split(" ");

if(cmd === `${prefix}play`){

```
function play(connection, message){
    var server = server[message.guild.id];

    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

    server.queue.shift();

    server.dispatcher.on("end",function(){
        if(server.queue[0]){
            play(connection, message);
        }else {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    })
}


if(!args[1]){
    message.channel.send("Pls provide a link!");
    return;
}

if(message.member.voiceChannel){
    message.channel.send("u need 2 be in a channel");
    return;
}

if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
    queue: []
}

var server = servers[message.guild.id];

server.queue.push(args[1]);

if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.channel.join().then(function(connection){
    play(connection, message);
})
```

}

this is my music bot code and ive tried alot of solutions but i still cant make it to join my vc and play the music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.member.voice.channel.channel` does not exist. remove the extra `.channel` at the end to fix that mistake. Otherwise, it appears `message.member.voice.channel` is null if that doesnt fix it.

If removing the extra `.channel` does not fix it, make sure you are in a voice channel.